# htaccess RewriteEngine On - Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, staging

i made a staging site on subdomain on var/www/stagin
but when I want to access it I get; Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. in htaccess I have RewriteEngine On enabled, when I disable it #RewriteEngine On, the staging site works. how to keep it enabled and not get this error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
htaccess permission is 0644

in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf I have AllowOverride All:

```
<Directory /var/www/> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All 
Require all granted
```

any help plz

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/417894/edit) to include the *full* content of your `.htaccess` file. It's possible there's an error in one of the directives in there. Also: Are you sure that [`mod_rewrite` is enabled](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-1-enabling-mod_rewrite)?